# Vicious wolves and the demise of the second order derivative test

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, maxima-minima

> The following modell describes an eco-system where $X$ is the number of rabbits and $Y$ is the number of vicious wolves. $r>0$ is the growth rate of the rabbits, and similarly $s>0$ is the growth rate of the wolves. $K>0$ and $L>0$ is the maximum population of respectively wolves and rabbits in the absence of preditors / prey.
>   \begin{align}  \dot{X} & = \frac{r}{K}X^2-rX+\alpha X Y = 0
> \tag{1} \\  \dot{Y} & = sY-\frac{s}{L}Y^2+\beta X Y = 0 \tag{2}  \end{align}
>   **a)** Use the Jacobian-matrix to determine analytically the dynamic of the system, find the equilibrium, and draw the state space of the system.

I tried solving the problem above, but ran into some difficulties. **Stationary points:**

\begin{align*}
 (0,0), \ 
    (0,L), \ 
    (K,0), \ 
    \left(\frac{K s (r - L \alpha)}{Z}, \frac{L r (K \beta + s)}{Z}\right)
\end{align*}

Where $Z:= K L \alpha\beta + r s$. Now I need to check if they are max, min or saddlepoints. The Jacobi matrix can be written as

\begin{align*}
 J(X,Y)
    = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \partial \dot{X} / \partial X & \partial \dot{X}/ \partial Y \\ 
        \partial \dot{Y} / \partial X & \partial \dot{Y}/ \partial Y
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \cfrac{2 r}{K} \, X - r + \alpha Y & \alpha X \\ 
        \beta Y & s - \cfrac{2 s}{L} \, Y + \beta X
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Hence the second order derivative test gives

\begin{align*}
 \bigl|J(0, L)\bigr| 
    & = 
    \begin{vmatrix}
     \alpha L - r & \phantom{-} 0 \\ 
        \beta L \phantom{- r.} & -s
    \end{vmatrix}
    =
    s(r-\alpha L) 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align}
 \left|J\left(\frac{K s (r - L \alpha)}{Z}, \frac{L r (K \beta + s)}{Z}\right)\right| 
    & = 
    \frac{1}{Z^2}
    \begin{vmatrix}
     r s (r-L\alpha) & \alpha s K (r - \alpha L) \\ 
        \beta r L (K\beta+s) & -rs(\beta K + s)
    \end{vmatrix}
    = 
    \frac{r s (\alpha L - r) (\beta K + s)}{Z}
\end{align}
I did not bother writing down the other ones as they were pretty straight forward to figure out. Now I have to look at the cases $\alpha L > r$, $\alpha L < r$ and $\alpha L = r$.

In the case $r < \alpha L$ then $(0,L)$ and $(K s (r - L \alpha)/Z, L r (K \beta + s)/Z)$ are saddle points. If $r > \alpha L$ then both are maxima, because $\partial\dot{X}/\partial X$ is positive for both points.

**My question is: How do I figure out what kind of points I have when $r = \alpha L$?**

Comment: The usual solution is to say that those are non-generic cases which never happen in real life. :-)

Comment: (By the way, why do you call this the second order derivative test? You're using *first* derivatives only.)

Comment: One more thing: "max/min" is not the correct terminology. You want to classify the equilibrium points into **stable** or **unstable** (and saddle point is a special kind of unstable equilibrium).

Comment: Using the first derivative of $\dot{X}$, which is the second derivative ;) Sorry about the terminology English is not my native language

Comment: You're taking derivatives of the *right-hand* side in the ODE $\dot X=f(X,Y)$, not the left-hand side. The second derivative of $\dot X(t)$ would be $\ddot X(t)$ which is something completely different; it doesn't make much sense to talk about the derivative of $dX/dt$ with respect to $X$.

Comment: Eh I have seen $\dot{X}$ being as the name of a function, however I can see how it can cause confusion.